High WMI cpu usage when listening to events
I have written the code below to listen to creation and deletion events of when specific applications are created/deleted, and also retrieve their process name, id, command line, using WMI, NotificationQuery, ExecQuery.
I noted that WmiPrvSE.exe is using "too much" CPU when my program is "idling", it's using like 1.5-2%.
My current code is:
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

enum EventType { QUERY, PROCESS_CREATION, PROCESS_DELETION };

class EventSink : public IWbemObjectSink
{
    LONG m_lRef = 0;
public:
    EventSink(){}

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef() 
    { 
        return InterlockedIncrement(&m_lRef);
    }

    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release()
    {
        LONG lRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_lRef);
        if(lRef == 0)
            delete this;
        return lRef;
    }

    void event(EventType eventType, const std::vector<IWbemClassObject*>& objList)
    {
        for (IWbemClassObject* obj : objList)
        {
            DWORD processId   = 0;
            std::wstring processName = L"";
            std::wstring commandLine = L"";

            VARIANT vtProp;
            HRESULT hr = obj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && vtProp.vt == VT_BSTR)
                processName = vtProp.bstrVal;
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            hr = obj->Get(L"ProcessId", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && vtProp.vt == VT_I4)
                processId = vtProp.uintVal;
            VariantClear(&vtProp);

            if (eventType == QUERY || eventType == PROCESS_CREATION)
            {
                hr = obj->Get(L"CommandLine", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && vtProp.vt == VT_BSTR)
                    commandLine = vtProp.bstrVal;
                VariantClear(&vtProp);
                //...
   
            }
            else if (eventType == PROCESS_DELETION)
            {
                //...
            }

            obj->Release();
        }
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppv)
    {
        if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IWbemObjectSink)
        {
            *ppv = (IWbemObjectSink *) this;
            AddRef();
            return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
        }
        else return E_NOINTERFACE;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE Indicate(LONG lObjectCount, IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *apObjArray)
    {
        std::map<EventType, std::vector<IWbemClassObject*>> eventMap;
        for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
        {
            VARIANT vtClass;
            HRESULT hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"__CLASS", 0, &vtClass, 0, 0);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
                continue;

            bool creationEvent = (wcscmp(vtClass.bstrVal, L"__InstanceCreationEvent") == 0);
            VariantClear(&vtClass);

            VARIANT vtTargetInstance;
            hr = apObjArray[i]->Get(L"TargetInstance", 0, &vtTargetInstance, 0, 0);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr) || vtTargetInstance.vt != VT_UNKNOWN)
                continue;
        
            IWbemClassObject* pTargetInstance = NULL;
            hr = vtTargetInstance.punkVal->QueryInterface(IID_IWbemClassObject, (void**)&pTargetInstance);
            if (!SUCCEEDED(hr))
                continue;

            VariantClear(&vtTargetInstance);
            eventMap[creationEvent ? PROCESS_CREATION : PROCESS_DELETION].emplace_back(pTargetInstance);          
        }

        for (auto it = eventMap.begin(); it != eventMap.end(); ++it)
        {
            event(it->first, it->second);
        }

        return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
    }

    HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE SetStatus(LONG lFlags, HRESULT hResult, BSTR strParam, IWbemClassObject __RPC_FAR *pObjParam)
    {
        return WBEM_S_NO_ERROR;
    }
};

class ProcessMonitor
{
public:
    ProcessMonitor()
    {
        HRESULT hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);        
        IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;
        hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&pLoc);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            std::cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object. Err code = 0x"  << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            return;
        }

        pSvc = NULL;
        hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(
            _bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), // WMI namespace
            NULL,                    // User name
            NULL,                    // User password
            0,                       // Locale             
            NULL,                    // Security flags
            0,                       // Authority       
            0,                       // Context object 
            &pSvc                    // IWbemServices proxy
        );

        if (FAILED(hres) || !pSvc || !pLoc)
        {
            std::cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            return;
        }

        hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(
            pSvc,                        // the proxy to set
            RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT,           // authentication service
            RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,            // authorization service
            NULL,                        // Server principal name
            RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,      // authentication level
            RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // impersonation level
            NULL,                        // client identity 
            EOAC_NONE                    // proxy capabilities     
        );

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            std::cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x"
                << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            return;
        }

        pSink = new EventSink;
        pSink->AddRef();
    }

    void query()
    {
        IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
        pSvc->ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t(wmiQuery.c_str()), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &pEnumerator);
        IWbemClassObject* pclsObj = NULL;
        ULONG uReturn = 0;

        std::vector<IWbemClassObject*> objList;
        while (pEnumerator)
        {
            HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
            if (0 == uReturn)
                break;
            objList.emplace_back(pclsObj);
        }        
    
        pSink->event(QUERY, objList);
        pEnumerator->Release();
    }

    void updateQuery(const std::wstring& processName)
    {
        processList.push_back(processName);

        wmiQuery = L"SELECT Name, CommandLine, ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE NAME = '";

        processCreationQuery = L"SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "
            L"'Win32_Process' AND (TargetInstance.Name = '"; // notepad.exe' OR TargetInstance.Name = 'CalculatorApp.exe')";

        processDeletionQuery = L"SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA "
            L"'Win32_Process' AND (TargetInstance.Name = '"; // notepad.exe' OR TargetInstance.Name = 'CalculatorApp.exe')";

        for (size_t i = 0; i < processList.size(); ++i)
        {
            processCreationQuery += processList[i] + L"'";
            processDeletionQuery += processList[i] + L"'";
            wmiQuery += processList[i] + L"'";
            if (i < processList.size() - 1)
            {
                wmiQuery += L" OR NAME = '";
                processCreationQuery += L" OR TargetInstance.Name = '";
                processDeletionQuery += L" OR TargetInstance.Name = '";
            }
            else if (i == processList.size() - 1)
            {
                processCreationQuery += L")";
                processDeletionQuery += L")";
            }
        }

        pSvc->CancelAsyncCall(pSink);

        BSTR queryLanguage = SysAllocString(L"WQL");

        // Query for process creation
        HRESULT hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
            queryLanguage,
            bstr_t(processCreationQuery.c_str()),
            WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS,
            NULL,
            pSink);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            std::wcout << L"ExecNotificationQueryAsync failed with = 0x" << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            return;
        }

        // Query for process deletion
        hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync(
            queryLanguage,
            bstr_t(processDeletionQuery.c_str()),
            WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS,
            NULL,
            pSink);

        if (FAILED(hres))
        {
            std::wcout << L"ExecNotificationQueryAsync failed with = 0x" << std::hex << hres << std::endl;
            CoUninitialize();
            return;
        }
    }

private:
    IWbemServices* pSvc;
    EventSink* pSink;
    std::wstring wmiQuery;
    std::wstring processCreationQuery;
    std::wstring processDeletionQuery;
    std::vector<std::wstring> processList;
};

int main()
{
    ProcessMonitor pm;
    pm.updateQuery(L"notepad.exe"); // At this point its already listening to create/deletion events
    pm.query(); // The call to query will be used to collect the processes running before the application started
    std::cin.get(); // Idle, but WmiPrvSE continues using high cpu
}

After pm.query() the process is "idling" but the CPU usage of WmiPrvSE.exe continues high, and when i close my process it also continues high, i need to reboot the pc to it "reset".
It's calling the query only once and then listening to the events, am I leaking something?
I also noted on Event Viewer > Application and Services Logs > Windows WMI-Activity > Operational that it is storing the following errors relative to my process:
Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine = DESKTOP-...; User = DESKTOP-...; ClientProcessId = 20240; Component = Unknown; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery - ROOT\CIMV2 : SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND (TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe'); ResultCode = 0x80041032; PossibleCause = Unknown

Id = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}; ClientMachine = DESKTOP-...; User = DESKTOP-...; ClientProcessId = 20240; Component = Core; Operation = Start IWbemServices::ExecNotificationQuery - ROOT\CIMV2 : SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' AND (TargetInstance.Name = 'notepad.exe'); ResultCode = 0x800706BA; PossibleCause = Could not send status to client


The event viewer entries seem reasonable. The first one is a WBEM_E_CALL_CANCELLED error, and the second has the error code translated into text. Either indicates that the session was terminated by the system, which is to be expected when the process terminates.

You could refer to the thread: WMI-Activity Event 5858 logged frequently with ResultCode 0x80041032

@Jeaninez-MSFT thanks but i already had read this thread, also, I'm calling the query with WBEM_INFINITE, I also get the same CPU usage issue without calling the query function and listening only to the events.

I suggest you could refer to the Docs:Troubleshoot WMI high CPU usage issues
WMI Troubleshooting
0x800706BA HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(RPC_S_SERVER_UNAVAILABLE) Firewall issue or server not available.Allow the "Remote Administration" rule in Windows Firewall.
